# How to insert specific data from a group of cells depending on the selected cell @VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I m really amateur in coding and this is my first try, i want to create a macro that depending on the selected cell (e.x A1) will open ie, insert login info from Column B and C  and enter the site.After some search i have finished most of it , but i cant specify the line i want to work with.
I need the macro to take info from the columns of the login and password respectively depending of the cell i select (example i select A1 the macro inserts data from B1 and C1. or i select A2 it goes from B2, C2 etc).
Here is the code ive managed to write till now

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Test()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "my site"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = Range("A1")
HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = Range("B1")
Application.SendKeys (ENTER)

End Sub
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
With Selection.Cells(1).EntireRow
    HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = .Cells(2).value
    HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = .Cells(3).value
End With
```

The `.Cells(1)` on `Selection` is to manage the case where the user might have selected multiple cells.  It might be safer to check that before proceeding though: in the case where `Selection.Cells.Count > 1` you could pop up a messagebox and exit.

Eg:

```
If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then 
   Msgbox "Select a cell first!"
   Exit Sub
End if

If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 then
    MsgBox "Select a single row!"
    Exit sub
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much , this solved my problem. However due to some site conflict i have to change from ie, do you think its possible to change it for some other browser? or it would be near impossible to do so?

Comment: You can look at Selenium and chrome - not something I've used though.